# iPhone - Objective C - PLCameraPreviewView class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

My app uses camera to take a photo.
When I open the camera the second time (after I opened it the first time and closed it),
the app crashes with this message:

```
*** -[PLCameraPreviewView isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4193380
```

what is PLCameraPreviewView?
do you know what is happening, I just use the following code to open the camera:

```
self.imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I have a UIView category which has a method:

+(UIView*)**firstResponder**;

when I change the name of this method to

+(UIView*)**theFirstResponder**;

the problem went away.

I guess we should not name the methods in our category similar to the built-in method names of that class.